# How to install Emoji on linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Fedora 17. I want to view Emoji icons on my computer. Currently I am seeing square tiles on most of the symbols in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji). Not sure if this has got to do with Character Map and how to get the required font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the [`gdouros-symbola-fonts` package](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Gdouros_Symbola): `pkcon install gdouros-symbola-fonts`. Then restart your browser and [that Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) should look much more interesting.

For anyone else not using Fedora, visit the [Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) page to download these and other fonts directly from their creator, George Douros.

Comment: Though it didn't state that it contains Emoji, but it does. Thanks!